# How to print before and after dot text Unix

Tags: shell

I am trying to print only specific output from sentence like below

Before and after dot text should be printed

```
InputVar="ABC SDFSG XYZ.AFGAJK JKK"
```

**Expected output :**

```
XYZ.AFGAJK
```

I am using cut command not working

```
echo "$InputVar" | cut -d'' -f2
```

Any other approach ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions.  `awk` with RS set to a space seems easiest. YMMV

```
$ echo "$InputVar" | cut -d ' ' -f 3
XYZ.AFGAJK
$ echo "$InputVar" | awk '/\./' RS=' '
XYZ.AFGAJK
$ echo "$InputVar" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(match($i,"\\.")) print $i}'
XYZ.AFGAJK
$ echo "$InputVar" | sed -n 's/.* \([^ .]*[.][^ .]*\) .*/\1/p'
XYZ.AFGAJK
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using cut:

If you really want to use `cut`, then you could try:

```
echo "$InputVar" | cut -d' ' -f3
```

Which uses a space character as a delimiter (you originally had an empty string, which is not allowed), and extracts field 3 rather than field 2.

## Using grep:

You can use `grep` rather than `cut`, to match & extract specifically what you want:

```
echo "$InputVar" | grep -Eo '[^ ]+\.[^ ]+'
```

### Explanation:

- The `-E` option is for extended regex
- The `-o` option is for extracting the matched component only
- The regex matches a literal `.`, surrounded by a non-empty sequence of non-space characters

## Comparing the two methods:

Either of these will work with your shown example. But, suppose the input string was instead:

```
InputVar="ABC SDFSG XYZ.AFGAJK JKK XYZ.ABC"
```

The version using `grep` would give all the matches (a literal `.` with non-space characters on either side).

Using `cut` however, you would need to specify the specific fields you want, i.e.

```
$ echo "$InputVar" | cut -d' ' -f3,5
XYZ.AFGAJK
XYZ.ABC
```

If you instead wanted just the `n`-th match, using the `grep` approach, you could use `sed` to select the `n`-th match, e.g.

```
$ echo "$InputVar" | grep -Eo '[^ ]+\.[^ ]+'
XYZ.AFGAJK
XYZ.ABC
$ echo "$InputVar" | grep -Eo '[^ ]+\.[^ ]+' | sed '1q;d'
XYZ.AFGAJK
$ echo "$InputVar" | grep -Eo '[^ ]+\.[^ ]+' | sed '2q;d'
XYZ.ABC
```